# Volume of a Sphere Segment Cut Out by Zigzag Motion of Radius Vector Through Sphere Center

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus

A closed loop curve on a sphere radius $R$ enclosing curved area $A$ subtends a solid angle $ A/R^2$ steridians at center of the sphere. Volume $V$ is enclosed by concurrent straight generators between the center and loop edge.

Prove that such a solid has volume $ V = A\, R/3. $

Comment: The volume $V$ is the union of infinitesimal pyramids having base area $dA$ and height $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following conventions for spherical coordinates

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad$[image]

Suppose that the origin of the coordinate system is located at the center of the sphere. Hence, by constructing a triple integral for the volume in spherical coordinates we have

$$\begin{align}
V&=\iiint dv \\
 &=\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta(\phi)}\int_{r=0}^{R}r^2 \sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi \\
&=\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta(\phi)} \left. \frac{r^3}{3}\right|_{0}^{R} \sin \theta d\theta d\phi\\
&=\frac{R^3}{3} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta(\phi)} \sin \theta  d\theta d\phi \\
&=\frac{R}{3} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta(\phi)} R^2 \sin \theta  d\theta d\phi \\
&=\frac{R}{3}\iint_{A}da \\
&=A\frac{R}{3}
\end{align}$$

That's it! :)